# Duvida de como fazer uma consulta a várias tabelas com uma palavra

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou montando um sistema de busca, onde o usuario digita em uma caixa de busca qualquer palavra, Exemplo "Programador", o mysql vai ter que procurar essa palavra em vários campos em varias tabela, se por acaso ele encontre essa palavra em algum lugar me retorne quem é o profissional que obtem essa palavra.

Abaixo estão as tabelas e a query que estou usando no momento, mas não é muito funcional.

Tabelas/colunas

**Profissional:**

id

Pri_nome

sobre_nome

**enderenco_profissional:**

id

id_profissional

estado

cidade

**historico_escolar:**

id

id_profissional

escolaridade

**experiencia:**

id

id_profissional

cargo

Query que estou tentando acertar!

```
SELECT a.id FROM profissional a, endereco_profissional b, historico_escola c, experiencia d WHERE a.pri_nome LIKE '%programador%' OR a.sobre_nome LIKE '%programador%' OR b.estado LIKE '%programador%' OR b.cidade LIKE '%programador%' OR c.escolaridade LIKE '%programador%' OR d.cargo LIKE '%programador%' OR a.id = b.id_profissional OR a.id = c.id_profissional OR a.id=d.id_profissional OR a.id=e.id_profissional OR a.id=f.id_profissional GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Acredito que fazendo relacionamento com as tabelas. Depois vc faz um select join com todas as tabelas de uma vez

Comment: Suas tabelas contém apenas essas colunas?

Comment: Não, todas elas contém id, a tabela principal e o profissional, e as outras contém id próprio e o id_profissional.

Comment: Já estão todas relacionadas.

Comment: Se ela estão relacionadas então basta fazer um select com join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turma acho que consegui.
Era apenas usar um pouco mais a lógica da cabeça com as portas or e and.

```
SELECT a.id FROM profissional a, endereco_profissional b, historico_escola c, experiencia d, area_interesse_profissional e, curso_extra f WHERE a.pri_nome LIKE '%programador%' OR a.sobre_nome LIKE '%programador%' OR (b.estado LIKE '%programador%' AND a.id = b.id_profissional) OR (b.cidade LIKE '%programador%' and a.id = b.id_profissional) OR (c.escolaridade LIKE '%programador%' AND  a.id = c.id_profissional) OR (d.cargo LIKE '%programador%' AND a.id=d.id_profissional)  GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM profissional prof  join enderenco_profissional end on pro.id = end.id  where pri_nome LIKE '%programador%' " Essa é uma maneira de juntar as tabelas.

Comment: Sempre utilizei esse meu método e nunca tive problema, mas qual a diferença dos dois?

Comment: No join vc faz um tabela a partir de outras ou seja vc mescla as tabelas. Veja esse conteúdo pra dar uma clareada http://vivenciandoti.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/sql-uso-do-join-em-clausulas-select.html?m=1

Comment: Faca um select join com suas tabelas e jogue no phpmyadmin assim vc vai visualizar o que estou falando